Laravel relation based on column from main table
So this is the query I have constructed so far
$data['requested_units'] = RequestedUnit::with([
    'user',
    'agent_warrants' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('type', RequestedUnit::AgentSecurityWarrant);
    }
])
->where('status', RequestedGrant::REQUESTED)
->get();

the problem is that it assumes the 'type' column is in the table 'agent_warrants' but actually it is in the parent table i-e RequestedUnit , how to specify this?

->with([ 'agent_warrants' => function($query)  {
$query->where('type',RequestedUnit::AgentSecurityWarrant)
}])

this assumes that type column is in agent_warrants , i want to specify that type columns is in the parent table requested_unit

You want to load agent_warrants when the type of RequestedUnit is RequestedUnit::AgentSecurityWarrant ?

@Maraboc yes  , exactly

@Arsalan Khan can't you do just  RequestedUnit::where('type',RequestedUnit::AgentSecurityWarrant) }]) and then ->with(['agent_warrants'])

@francisco actually there are other relations as well , so i can't do that , i have to do it conditionally

ok, then do like $q->where('requested_units.type',

You can't specify that in the query. with will load the relationships for every result.
However, you can use load after getting the results on a subset you obtain with a filtering method such a where, filter or reject
$data['requested_units'] = RequestedUnit::with([
    'user',
])
->where('status', RequestedGrant::REQUESTED)
->get();

$data['requested_units']
    ->where('type', RequestedUnit::AgentSecurityWarrant) // collection method
    ->load('agent_warrants');

